# What is the best way to return services in AngularJs? And Why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following two codes:

```
angular.module('servicefunction',[]).
factory('checkservice',[function(){ 
    this.x = function(num){
        return num;
    }
 return this;
}]);
```

And the next one creating some object and returning it:

```
angular.module('servicefunction',[]).
factory('checkservice',[function(){ 
   var x = {};
   x.number = function(){
  }
  return x;
}]);
```

What is the best way to return from a `Service` and why? Does it make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

It depends, but basically I use 2 versions

```
// useful for single function, called as checkServ()
angular.module('serv',[]).
    factory('checkServ',[function(){ 
      return function(){
          //stuff
          //can be called with arguments
      }
}]);
// called as checkServ.func() or checkServ.prop
angular.module('serv',[]).
    factory('checkServ',[function(){ 
      return {
          prop: 'data',
          func: function() {
               //stuff here
          }
      }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of convention. Stick it with one that's best suited for your coding style.

Each of your example use the factory pattern, and angular services are constructed around the factory pattern. Another way you can use is:

```
angular.module('servicefunction',[]).
factory('checkservice',[function(){ 
   return {
      getX : function() {
          return x;
      }
   }
}]);
```

Comment: I dont understand something, when I use `this`, still an object is being sent, does angular initiate the factory object by itself ? Whats the difference?

Comment: Yes, is initiating the factory object itself. And when you are defining the factory by wrapping it inside your module you are making reference to the factory itself which contains the exported function too.